# How to make list selection option unique in mat-selection-list?

Tags: javascript, angular, list, angular-material2

I have a use case wherein I need to make a list selection unique in Angular2 Material mat-selection list..

I have gone through

```
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/list/list-demo.html
```

and

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/list/selection-list.spec.ts

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

I am wrapping my head around this exact same problem.
My first approach was to hide the checkbox of the Material Selection List.
And on the (selectionChange) calling a function that dismissed my modal and sent the data back to its parent.

select-dialog-component.html

```
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value" (selectionChange)="onSelectedOptionsChange(value)"> {{option.name}} </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

select-dialog-component.ts

```
onSelectedOptionsChange(value) {this.dialogRef.close(value);}
```

And also added in the css (as I commented above)

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox {display: none;}
```

And that was it. It works. It looks cool, and everything is nice, until you realize it lags a little bit. And then you figure out that if you toggle the modal many times, it starts lagging a lot.

---

So, here my second approach (which also seems much more correct).
Instead of using mat-selection-list use mat-list and put mat-buttons inside.

select-dialog-component-v2.html

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="onSelectedOptionsChange(option.value)">
    <button mat-button> {{option.name}} </button></mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Hope it helps!